# Can't show image uploaded with ImageField in template

Tags: python, django

So, I have a blog application, when I want to add cover image to article with ImageField file browser my image name is getting red in PyCharm and not showing in template. But when I inspect its HTML codes source, path to image is true. Here are my codes:

`articles.html`:

`<a href="/"><img src="{{ article.image.url }}" class="image"/></a>`

`settings.py`:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

`models.py`:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = HTMLField()
    # image = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, null=True, editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = latin_slugify(self.title)
        super(Article, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

`urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 0):

It was because of `DEBUG = False`, changin its value to `True` solved the problem.